# trying to match 2 values in JSON array and get the corresponding value with in the array

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I am trying to compare the age and gender in JSON and trying to print the corresponding name for the details. but its nor working for me.

```js
_.each(response.details, function(value, key){
   if (value.age == "12" && value.gender == "male") {
            console.log(value.name + "name")
   }
});
```

```js
JSON:

details: [
{
  age: "12",
  gender: "male",
  name: "danny"
},
{
  age: "13",
  gender: "male",
  name: "sunny"
},
{
  age: "12",
  gender: "female",
  name: "janny"
},
{
  age: "14",
  gender: "female",
  name: "josef"
}
],
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Looks to be working fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/k1ye5bm9/

Comment: It doesn't matter here, but it's better practice to use === to match values in if statements. For an explanation see the response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

your code just works, I added `_.result()` and `_.find()` functions:

```js
var details = [{
  age: "12",
  gender: "male",
  name: "danny"
}, {
  age: "13",
  gender: "male",
  name: "sunny"
}, {
  age: "12",
  gender: "female",
  name: "janny"
}, {
  age: "14",
  gender: "female",
  name: "josef"
}];

console.log(_.result(_.find(details, {
  age: '12',
  gender: 'male'
}), 'name') + 'name');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use lodash for this, javascript provides this support natively via **filter**!

```js
var details = [{
  age: "12",
  gender: "male",
  name: "danny"
}, {
  age: "13",
  gender: "male",
  name: "sunny"
}, {
  age: "12",
  gender: "female",
  name: "janny"
}, {
  age: "14",
  gender: "female",
  name: "josef"
}];

var results = details.filter(function(row) {
 if (row.age == "12" && row.gender == "male") {
  return true;
 }
});
results.forEach(function(result) {
  console.log(result.name + ' name');
})
```